# every time I try to rig clothes with body the sleeves bend

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, bones

I'm a blender newbie, when I try to rig clothes with bones the sleeves bend and I don't know how to solve this problem, I saw many vids about common rigging problems but I still don't know how to fix it.
I tried to rig the jacket with automatic weight and I tried to rig it with data transfer, both of them didn't work.
Every time I try to rig any thing, the sleeves always bend, please someone help.
here the project file: [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show us wire of cloth ... also try to go Cloth Presets and choose Silk

Comment: sry I'm a beginner, idk what is a wire of cloth, but I will search about it, thx btw

Comment: ok I tried to choose silk and it didn't work, I'm so lost Idk what to do

Comment: I mean switch display type to wire mode so we can see the topology of your mesh ... or share your simplified file via https://blend-exchange.com to let us see your setup.

Comment: I put the file in the description so you can see it by yourself, thanks again :)

Comment: The main issue here is that your coat is not in the same rest pose as your character+armature.  For it to work properly with the armature, it needs to be.  To see your rest pose, select your armature and in properties/object data/skeleton click on the "rest pose" button.

Comment: wait I'll try to do what your saying, thank you so much

Comment: thank you so much it worked, y'all helped me so much <3